# Javascript mute/unmutebutton

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out what to do with a mute/unmute button in my JavaScript, I've been on this for hours now! Basically I've got my mute button working, and it mutes the video, I'm now trying to make the same button unmute the video. Any ideas?

```
function MuteUnmutevideo() {
  if (video.muted = true) {
    //toggle button caption
    MuteButton.innerHTML = "Muted";
  } else {
    if (video.muted === true)
      //toggle button caption
      MuteButton.innerHTML = "unmuted";
  } //end else
```

Comment: Why are both parts of the if checking if the video is muted?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your button is muting the video is because you are doing an assignment rather than a comparison inside of your first if.

`if(video.muted = true)` rather than `if(video.muted == true)`.

The reason why it doesn't unmute the video is because you have no code that would do that.

You should change your function to read:

```
function MuteUnmutevideo() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    MuteButton.innerHTML = video.muted ? 'Muted' : 'Unmuted';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `==` the comparison, not `=` the assignment in the first if statement.

```
function MuteUnmutevideo () {
    if ( video.muted == true ) {
        //toggle button caption
        MuteButton.innerHTML = "Muted";
    } else {
        //toggle button caption
        MuteButton.innerHTML = "unmuted";
    }//end else
}
```

If that doesn't float your boat, you can use a ternary operation (as suggested by Comptonburger) to accomplish the same thing:

```
function MuteUnmutevideo() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    MuteButton.innerHTML = video.muted ? 'Muted' : 'Unmuted';
}
```